# What comes after drawRect()

Tags: ios, swift

i was wondering how to execute code after drawRect() of a UIView is called?

Is there a afterdrawRect Hook/Method in the iOS render cycle?

Why?
I want to show a Button in the InterfaceBuilder (via IBDesignable) but hide it in the final product.

```
@IBDesignable class FakeUIButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var fillColor: UIColor = UIColor.purpleColor() {
        didSet {
            layer.backgroundColor = fillColor.CGColor
            self.alpha = 0.5
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        layer.backgroundColor = fillColor.CGColor
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()  // called to late in render cycle
    }

}
```

Comment: you can hide the Button in viewDidLoad

Comment: Can you explain why you want to show a button in IB but hide it at runtime?

Comment: To have some kind of "hotspot" do build a quick prototype with just jpgs in the background. I added the code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
```

to prepare your view for displaying in IB, the code in this won't run in the app itself.
Or you can use

```
#if !TARGET_INTERFACE_BUILDER
    // this code will run in the app itself
#else
    // this code will execute only in IB
#endif
```

to only run code, when displaying in the IB.